# Inverse of a matrix mod 26

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to find the inverse of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
 4  &8 \\ 
 5  &7
\end{bmatrix} \mod 26$. However the determinant of this matrix is 14 so I cannot use Cramer's rule and each time I try to solve simply by elimination, I end up with non-invertible elements in the resulting matrix.

For example, multiplying the second row by 15:
$$\left.\begin{matrix}
 4&8 \\ 
 23&1 
\end{matrix}\right|
\begin{matrix}
 1&0 \\ 
 0&15 
\end{matrix}$$

Then adding the second row the first:
$$\left.\begin{matrix}
 1&9 \\ 
 23&1 
\end{matrix}\right|
\begin{matrix}
 1&15 \\ 
 0&15 
\end{matrix}$$
Adding 3 times the first row to the second:
$$\left.\begin{matrix}
 1&9 \\ 
 0&2 
\end{matrix}\right|
\begin{matrix}
 1&15 \\ 
 3&8 
\end{matrix}$$

At this point, 2 doesn't have an inverse mod 26 and $2x\equiv9 \pmod{26}$ has no solution. I've tried a number of different combinations of row operations. How can I find the inverse of this matrix?

Comment: If the determinant is not invertible, then the matrix is not invertible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The multiplication formula $$\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$$ is true whenever $A,B$ have elements from a commutative ring. If $A$ is invertible with inverse $A^{-1}$ then $$1=\det(AA^{-1}) = \det(A)\det(A^{-1})$$ so $\det(A)$ is invertible with inverse $\det(A^{-1}).$ So for $A$ to be invertible it is necessary that $\det(A)$ be invertible, which is not the case here. A stronger result is that $A$ is invertible if and only if $\det(A)$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\: mod\,\ 26\!:\ \left[\begin{array}{c} 4 & 8\\ 5 & 7\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}x\\ \rm y\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c}0\\ \rm 0\end{array}\right]\ $ has solution $\:\left[\begin{array}{c}13\\ \rm 13\end{array}\right]\: $so the matrix is not invertible.

Indeed, if it it were invertible then multiplying by the inverse shows $\ \smash[t]{\rm \left[\begin{array}{c}x\\ \rm y\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c}0\\ \rm 0\end{array}\right]}$